# При установке Win не видит hdd

Tags: windows, windows-10, драйвер, intel, msi

Чтобы установить `win` с нуля удалил все разделы дисков. Даже не знал что у меня их два : один `SSD` второй `HDD`. Сейчас виден `SSD`, `HDD` при установке нет, хотя `BIOS` видит. Пытался установить драйвера, может не те пытался установить, но ничего не получилось. Подскажите что можно сделать. Компьютер `MSI GP62m 7RD Leopard`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы затёрли разметку диска, если есть возможность установить на USB образ acronis disk director, с помощью него осуществить ручную размету HDD диска. Тогда установщик его точно должен увидеть. Еще как вариант можно попробовать изъять SSD и запустить установку только с HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем ясен вопрос. Если Вы говорите что БИОС "видит", что мешает сделать **загрузочную флешку с Windows**, изменить в биосе **приоритет загрузки** (установить высшим приоритетом загрузку с Вашей флешки) и установить систему на этот самый **HDD**, предварительно отформатировав диск (форматирование будет предложено во время установки).